# useState not updating correctly with socket.io

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io, react-hooks, state

I am pulling data via socket.io but when listening for incoming messages from the server my state is not updating correctly.

I can see the data is being pulled correctly from the socket (50 reqs peer second) but `setQuotes`  just replaces the existing item with the new item returned from the server (so my state always has a length of one).

```
  const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState([])
 const subscribe = () => {
    let getQuote = 'quote.subscribe';
    socket.emit(getQuote, {});
    socket.on('listenAction', function (msg) {
        setQuotes([...quotes, msg]) // This just replace the entire state instead of adding items to the existing array
    }); 
}
```

Subscribe // Open web socket stream

Comment: can you try setQuotes(oldQuotes => [...oldQuotes, msg])?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this, I am facing the same issue?

Answer (score 7):

You need to move the listener outside of the subscribe function.
Since it is a sideEffect you should wrap it in `React.useEffect`
It's also a good idea to use functional setstate to read previous values.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('listenAction', function (msg) {
        setQuotes((quotes) => [...quotes, msg])
    }); 
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example you use  setState like this

```
setQuotes([...quotes, msg])
```

And every time you get message, javascript engine tries to find "quotes" variable in scope of this function

```
function (msg) {
```

It can not find it here and move to the scope, where this function was defined ( scope of component function).

For every function call, there is new scope. And react calls component function for each render. So, your function with "msg" in arguments, where you use setQuotes, every time uses "quotes" state from first render.

In first render you have an empty array.

Then you have `[...firstEmptyArray, firstMessage]`

Then you have `[...firstEmptyArray, secondMessage]`

Then you have `[...firstEmptyArray, thirdMessage].`

Probably, you can fix it if you will use setQuotes like;

```
setQuotes(oldQuotes => [...oldQuotes, msg]);
```

In this way it will use previousValue for calclulating new one.

PS. Be aware of not to call your subscribe function directly in each render and put it in useEffect with correct dependency array as second argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concat func over here
`setQuotes(prevState => prevState.concat(msg))`